# SSMS T-SQL set column for duplicate row number

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a database with approximately 10 million rows (and 20 columns - about 4 GB) where about 10% of the rows have a duplicate column.  Database is in SQL Server 2014 Express and using SSMS.

I created a new column CNT (int, null) to count the occurrences of each row where I have a duplicate ID. Desired result would look like:

```
ID     CNT
100    1
100    2
101    1
102    1
102    2
103    1
104    1
```

Not being really familiar with advanced SQL capabilities I did some research and came up with using a CTE to set the CNT column.  Worked fine on a small test table - but it was obvious this is not the way to go for a large table (I killed it after 5+ hours on a pretty decent system.)

Here's the code that I attempted to implement:

```
with CTE as
(select dbo.database.id, dbo.database.cnt,
 RN = row_number() over (partition by id order by id)
 from dbo.databasee)
update CTE set CNT = RN
```

Column ID is of type Int.  All columns allow nulls - there are no keys or indexed columns.

Comment: Can I check why you want to have CNT values stored as a column in your table? I mean, how would you use this stored data later on in your application/other queries?

Comment: If you have no indexes then the query plan would be something like sort the 10 million ids then do the row numbering and the update back onto the base table. Difficult to see how that would take 5 hours. What wait types do you see when it executes?

Comment: @shree.pat18 It is a big flat file that was likely created from a view of a relational database.  In extracting some info I need to make sure I don't grab 2nd or 3rd duplicate ID rows - but I can't delete those rows from the database because other columns have data of interest (even in the duplicated ID row).

Comment: @MartinSmith the CTE update code snippet above ran 5+ hours when I decided to kill it - don't understand the question about "wait types", sorry.

Comment: @RPMcCormick If your objective is to filter out rows when retrieving, I would suggest that you simply filter them out using your CTE with a where clause.

Comment: you could have been blocked by a lock held by an other  long running transaction for example rather than actually busy doing anything. You can poll `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` whilst it's executing and filter on that sessionid to get a quick idea.

Comment: epilog: after killing the SQL code noted in the OP it took SQL server 2+ hours to rectify the database (the log file had grown to 4+ GB) ... so clearly it had been processing something - but I have no idea how far from completion it was ... end result: the CTE was neither effective or efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Martin is right, I can only offer an alternate solution than the CTE at the moment.  Make a new table exactly like your old one, and insert the old table's data into it with this.

```
INSERT INTO newTable
SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID)
FROM oldTable;
```

Then you can delete your old table.  Definitely not a perfect solution, but it should work.

Comment: A Cte is not a saved resultset. It is like a view. And is updatable in the manner the OP is using.

Comment: In the end creating a new table without the dupes was the best solution - the database was static so it was fine to just used the non-dupe table for the few queries I needed to generate where dupes were an issue